# Generate Interpolation Function from points PHP

Tags: php, math, interpolation

I need to make a PHP script that generates the interpolation function from the set of points.

I have decided to use the Lagrange Interpolation because it was easiest for me to find the example that generates the function from a list of input points. The issues with other methods is that I couldn't find an example that generates the function -> all other examples for all other interpolations only generate additional points and not the function out of the existing points.

The source that I've used to find the example for the Lagrange Interpolation is: http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/Math420/Section_3_1.pdf

I've decided to replicate this example in my PHP code.

```
/**
 * Generate one basis polynomial function
 * @param type $points array of points
 * @param type $basisPolynomial Each basis polynomial will be stored in the array of values so that it can be appended to the final function
 * @param type $allXValues all x values for the point
 * @param type $i current index of the basis polynomial
 */
function generateBasisPolynomial(&$basisPolynomial, $allXValues, $i) {
    $basisPolynomial[$i] = "(";
    $divisor = "(";
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($allXValues); $j++) {
        if ($j == $i) {
            continue;
        }
        $basisPolynomial[$i] .= "(x-$allXValues[$j])*";
        $divisor .="($allXValues[$i]-$allXValues[$j])*";
    }
    //multiply the divisor by 1, because the previous loop has * at the end of the equation
    $divisor .="1)";
    $basisPolynomial[$i] .="1)/$divisor";
}

/**
 * Function that generates the Lagrange interpolation from the list of points
 * @param type $points
 * @return string
 */
function generateLagrangeInterpolation($points) {
    $numberOfPoints = count($points);
    if ($numberOfPoints < 2) {
        return "NaN";
    } else {
        //source http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/Math420/Section_3_1.pdf
        //for each point, construct the basis polynomial
        //for a sequence of x values, we will have n basis polynomials,
        //Example:
        //if we, for example have a sequence of four points, with their sequence of x values being {x0,x1,x2,x3}
        //then we construct the basis polynomial for x0 by doing the following calculation:
        //F(x) = ((x-x1)*(x-x2)*(x-x3))/((x0-x1)*(x0-x2)*(x0-x3)) -> where x is an unknown variable.
        $basisPolynomial = array();
        //get all x values from the array of points so that we can access them by index
        $allXValues = array_keys($points);
        $allYValues = array_values($points);
        //Because the Y values are percentages, we want to divide them by 100.
        $allYValues = array_map(function($val) {
            return $val / 100;
        }, $allYValues);

        $returnFunction = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfPoints; $i++) {
            generateBasisPolynomial($basisPolynomial, $allXValues, $i);
            //multiply this basis polynomial by y value
            $returnFunction .="$allYValues[$i]*$basisPolynomial[$i]+";
        }
        //Append 0 to the end of the function because the above loop returns a function with a +
        //at the end so we want to make it right
        $returnFunction .="0";
        echo $returnFunction;
    }
}

//$points = array("4.1168" => "0.213631", "4.19236" => "0.214232", "4.20967" => "0.21441", "4.46908" => "0.218788");
$points = array("0.1" => "5", "0.3" => "10", "0.5" => "30", "0.6" => "60", "0.8" => "70");
generateLagrangeInterpolation($points);
```

What I am getting as a result is the following function:

```
0.05*((x-0.3)*(x-0.5)*(x-0.6)*(x-0.8)*1)/((0.1-0.3)*(0.1-0.5)*(0.1-0.6)*(0.1-0.8)*1)+0.1*((x-0.1)*(x-0.5)*(x-0.6)*(x-0.8)*1)/((0.3-0.1)*(0.3-0.5)*(0.3-0.6)*(0.3-0.8)*1)+0.3*((x-0.1)*(x-0.3)*(x-0.6)*(x-0.8)*1)/((0.5-0.1)*(0.5-0.3)*(0.5-0.6)*(0.5-0.8)*1)+0.6*((x-0.1)*(x-0.3)*(x-0.5)*(x-0.8)*1)/((0.6-0.1)*(0.6-0.3)*(0.6-0.5)*(0.6-0.8)*1)+0.7*((x-0.1)*(x-0.3)*(x-0.5)*(x-0.6)*1)/((0.8-0.1)*(0.8-0.3)*(0.8-0.5)*(0.8-0.6)*1)+0
```

I don't care that the expression is simplified and calculated fully (however if you have any advice or code that could do that for me it would be a huge plus).

If I look at the simplified expression it looks something like this:

```
(47500*x^4-79300*x^3+42245*x^2-8699*x+480)/(-840)
```

However if I try to paste that function into http://fooplot.com -> I get that the graph is passing through the points defined as the input parameters, however, I'm not sure if the graph for the other points is correct as it looks like it's Y values go into minus values when X <=0 or x>=1.

Do you advise that I use the different function or the existing error in the interpolation can be reduced if I had more input points? I have to be honest that I am a poor mathematician so any real example of a more accurate method or example in the code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you're doing in reality here is generating a string which contains an expression which can potentially be evaluated.  Instead of `x` you can write `$x` to that function and then do `$x = <point that i need evaluated at>;  eval(generateLagrangeInterpolation($points));` however a much better solution is to implement a function that is the actual Lagrange polynomial (perhaps based on one of the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Definition)) like e.g. `function Lagrange($points, $x) { /* calculate the polynomial value at x */ }`

Comment: Hi @apokryfos, I can see that my code corectly implements Example 1 and 2 detailed on the wiki link you have provided.

The eval does not work If I try to apply it on the function that has the polynomials and unknown variables. I know that I can use it when I substitute the `x` with real values What I really want is only an interpolation function that I can use to construct a graph, when the input parameters are points. I just want to confirm if my implementation looks correct and if there is any advice on how the equation can be simplified in PHP when there are unknown variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the current algorithm for Lagrange interpolation method provides the correct results. To correct the errors in calculation, more base points can be provided. Also, to multiply the unknown variables in mathematic function, a function example was left in one of the answers.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try:

```
 function basisPolynomial($points, $j, $x) {
        $xj = $points[$j][0]; //Assume a point is an array of 2 numbers
        $partialProduct = 1;
         //Product loop
        for ($m = 0;$i < count($points);$m++) { 
             if ($m === $j) { continue; }                 
             $partialProduct *= ($x - $points[$m][0])/($xj-$points[$m][0]);
        }
        return $partialProduct;
 }

 function lagrangePolynomial($points,$x) {
        $partialSum = 0;
        for ($j = 0;$j < count($points);$j++) {
            $partialSum += $points[$j][1]*basisPolynomial($points,$j,$x);
        }
        return $partialSum;
 }
```

Now if you need to plot it you can generate a list of points that can be used in a plotting function e.g.

```
$points = <my points>; 
$plotPoints = [];
for ($i = 0;$i < 10;$i+= 0.1) { //for example 
    $plotPoints[] = [ $i, lagrangePolynomial($points,$i) ];
}
```

If you want to just use the to directly plot you need to use a plotting tool like gnuplot to define the functions and have it determine how to plot them.

Update: http://www.physics.brocku.ca/Courses/5P10/lectures/lecture_10_handout.pdf seems to have a gnuplot example of exactly what you need but it feels like cheating of sorts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much familiarized with the object oriented implementation of php, but in java I do this little baby ;)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Run{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] parameters = new int[]{-1, 2, 4, 3};
    Binom b = new Binom(1, 1, parameters[1], 0);
    Polinom p = new Polinom(b);
    for(int i = 2; i < parameters.length; i++)
      p.joinBinom(new Binom(1, 1, -1 * parameters[i], 0));
    System.out.println(p.toString() + " / (" + getDenominator(parameters) + ")");
  }

  public static int getDenominator(int[] params){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < params.length; i++)
      result *= params[0] - params[i];
    return result;
  }
}

class Monomial{
  private int constant = 1;
  private int pow = 0;

  public int getConstant(){
    return this.constant;
  }

  public void sumConstant(int value){
    this.constant += value;
  }

  public boolean hasVariable(){
    return this.pow > 0;
  }

  public int getPow(){
    return this.pow;
  }

  public Monomial(int constant, int pow){
    this.constant = constant;
    this.pow = pow;
  }

  public ArrayList<Monomial> multiply(Binom a){
    Monomial first = new Monomial(this.constant * a.getFirst().getConstant(), this.pow + a.getFirst().getPow());
    Monomial second = new Monomial(this.constant * a.getSecond().getConstant(), this.pow + a.getSecond().getPow());
    System.out.print("\t" + this.toString() + "\t* (" + a.getFirst().toString() + " " + a.getSecond().toString() + ")");
    System.out.print("\t= " + first.toString() + "\t");
    System.out.println(second.toString());
    return (new Binom(first, second)).toList();
  }

  public String toString(){
    String result = "";
    if(this.constant == 1){
      if(!this.hasVariable())
        result += this.constant;
    }
    else
      result += this.constant;
    if(this.hasVariable()){
      result += "X";
      if(this.pow > 1)
        result += "^" + this.pow;
    }
    return result;
  }
}

class Binom{
  private Monomial first;
  private Monomial second;

  public Monomial getFirst(){
    return this.first;
  }

  public Monomial getSecond(){
    return this.second;
  }

  public Binom(int constant1, int pow1, int constant2, int pow2){
    this.first = new Monomial(constant1, pow1);
    this.second = new Monomial(constant2, pow2);
  }

  public Binom(Monomial a, Monomial b){
    this.first = a;
    this.second = b;
  }

  public ArrayList<Monomial> toList(){
    ArrayList<Monomial> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(this.first);
    result.add(this.second);
    return result;
  }
}

class Polinom{
  private ArrayList<Monomial> terms = new ArrayList<>();

  public Polinom(Binom b){
    this.terms.add(b.getFirst());
    this.terms.add(b.getSecond());
  }

  private void compact(){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.terms.size(); i++){
      Monomial term = this.terms.get(i);
      for(int j = i + 1; j < this.terms.size(); j++){
        Monomial test = this.terms.get(j);
        if(term.getPow() == test.getPow()){
          term.sumConstant(test.getConstant());
          this.terms.remove(test);
          j--;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void joinBinom(Binom b){
    ArrayList<Monomial> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Monomial t : this.terms){
      result.addAll(t.multiply(b));
    }
    this.terms = result;
    this.compact();
  }

  public String toString(){
    String result = "";
    for(Monomial t : this.terms)
      result += (t.getConstant() < 0 ? " " : " +") + t.toString();
    return "(" + result + ")";
 }

}
```

which return:

```
X   * (X -4)    = X^2   -4X
2   * (X -4)    = 2X    -8
X^2 * (X -3)    = X^3   -3X^2
-2X * (X -3)    = -2X^2 6X
-8  * (X -3)    = -8X   24
( +X^3 -5X^2 -2X +24) / (-60)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as an answer as this is something what I was looking for. I can easily convert this to php.

Comment: self yourself n___n